# Python subprocess.Popen to use git pager

Tags: python, git, subprocess, pager

I'm stuck at a point where I can't get my python subprocess call for "git show" to run though the core.pager.

In my ~/.gitconfig I have specified a core pager;

```
[core]
    pager = cat -vet
```

And when I run this through subprocess (Popen or check_output)

```
cmd = ['git', '-C', repo, 'show', r'{0}:{1}'.format(commit, filename)]
stdout = subprocess.check_output(cmd)
```

The output I get have not run through the cat pager (the lines would end with '$')

When I run it myself from the cli, the output does go through the pager.
How should I do the call to subprocess to get the "git show" command to run through the core.pager?

Comment: Instead of `subprocess.check_output`, try it with `subprocess.call`.

Comment: With call I would not be able to capture the output of the command which is a requirement in this case unfortunately

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK, `git` only post-process output through the configured pager when output is directed to a terminal. Since you are using `subprocess.check_output`, the output from `git` command is redirected to a pipe (to allow to give it to Python caller). As such `core.pager` is not called.

It you want to get a post-processed output, you will have to do it *by hand*

Assuming you want to use `cat -vet` as a post-processing filter, you could do:

```
cmd = ['git', '-C', repo, 'show', r'{0}:{1}'.format(commit, filename)]
p1 = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout = subprocess.PIPE)
filter = [ '/bin/cat', '-vet' ]
p2 = subprocess.Popen(filter, stdout = subprocess.PIPE, stdin = p1.stdout)
p2.wait()
stdout = p2.stdout.read()
```

Comment: Thanks for clearing it up a bit. The problem I have though is that if the output is not processed through a pager first the control characters in the output will be interpreted (eg backspace etc) which is I want to avoid and then the by hand approach will have broken input already.

Comment: @max7: What do you mean by *the by hand approach will have broken input already*? `stdout` variable will get the **exact** output of `git -C ... | /usr/bin/cat -vet`. Is it not what you want?

Comment: When "git show" runs without a pager, the output sometimes contains a carriage return (^M) which will be interperated by the shell as an actuall carriage return and when passing/piping the output to cat the line will still be split incorrectly. When getting the git show output directly through cat will re-print the control char as the text ^M instead which is more desirable. Does that make sense?

Comment: @max7: Try it, and if the content of `stdout` is not useable, ask a new question with more details and citing this one as reference. Here the content of stdout **has been passed through the filter** because it is the output of `cat`, not of `git`.

Comment: i think you're right. I think i found the possible issue of me using the .splitlines on the output which is probably what is actually breaking it. Thanks for your help.